# Java Insertionsort Array [I@6af62373

Tags: java

I do not understand why not works my programm. 
I get  only this [I@6af62373
I know it's a very simple problem but I have no Idea. 
if someone speaks german can answer me to german.

public class InsertSort {
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
   int [] myAr = {8, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    for(int i = 0; i < myAr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(sort(myAr));
    }

}
```

public static  int[] sort(int[] myAr){

```
        int m,j;
        for (int i = 1; i < myAr.length; i++){
              j = i;
              m = myAr[i];
              while (j > 0 && myAr[j-1] > m) {
                     /*verschiebe myAr[j-1] nach rechts */
                      myAr[j] = myAr[j-1];
                      j--;
               }
               myAr[j] = m;
               }
    return  myAr;
```

}
}

Comment: In short, use `Arrays.toString(sort(myAr))`

Comment: Lots of Thanks Sam,
If you know another solution you can tell me please, for example without toString.

Comment: You can also use a loop to print each element of the array individually: `for (int x : myAr) { System.out.println(x); }`

Comment: It only get Array numbers without sorting but thanks however.

Comment: I should have been clearer; if you want to iterate the sorted array you can do `for (int x : sort(myAr)) { System.out.println(x); }`

Comment: yes it works, Thank you